# Getting error while starting development server of Vite

Tags: reactjs, node.js, vite, yarnpkg, windows-11

I'm getting error while starting my development server. My application is in React Js. When I'm starting same application on my Laptop which is using Linux, everything is working fine in my Laptop but, when I'm starting development server in my PC which is using Windows 11, I'm getting this error.
I'm using NodeJs v18.12.0. Yes, when I'm trying to start my application in my PC using npm, everything just working fine. Maybe, there is something wrong with yarn. I'm using 1.22.21 version of yarn

These are error logs:

```
  The service was stopped: write EPIPE
    at C:\Users\mfaha\Desktop\...\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1110:28
    at responseCallbacks.<computed> (C:\Users\mfaha\Desktop\...\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:703:9)
    at afterClose (C:\Users\mfaha\Desktop\...\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:693:28)
    at C:\Users\mfaha\Desktop\...\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:2163:11
    at onwriteError (node:internal/streams/writable:418:3)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:84:21)
3:57:52 pm [vite] error while updating dependencies:
Error: The service is no longer running: write EPIPE
    at C:\Users\mfaha\Desktop\...\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1083:25
    at sendRequest (C:\Users\mfaha\Desktop\...\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:699:14)
    at buildOrContextContinue (C:\Users\mfaha\Desktop\...\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1081:5)
    at C:\Users\mfaha\Desktop\...\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:993:11
```

---

```
C:\Users\mfaha\Desktop\..\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1110
                    reject(new Error(error2));
                           ^

Error: The service was stopped
    at C:\Users\mfaha\Desktop\...\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1110:28
    at responseCallbacks.<computed> (C:\Users\mfaha\Desktop\...\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:703:9)
    at Socket.afterClose (C:\Users\mfaha\Desktop\...\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:693:28)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:525:35)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1359:12)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)

Node.js v18.12.0
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

This is my Package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "...",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "vite --force",
    "build": "vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext js,jsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.20.1",
    "react-typing-effect": "^2.0.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.37",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.15",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react-swc": "^3.5.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.16",
    "eslint": "^8.53.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.33.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.4",
    "postcss": "^8.4.32",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.6",
    "vite": "^5.0.0"
  }
}
```

When I'm starting development server in my Linux machine using yarn, everything just working fine but, when I'm trying to start development server using yarn in my windows 11 PC, It's not starting but, when I'm trying to start development server in my windows 11 PC, using npm everything working fine.

Comment: When, I'm trying to run dev server over and over again, suddenly it's getting start.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Guys, if you want me to add more details, let me know please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution, It was happening because of Smadav anti-virus, I disabled auto-blocking and then, it worked.